# Replace string from returned string

Tags: php, string, wordpress

I have a function which returning HTML form. **Before the particular form appended to the HTML, I have to make a string replacement.** I have tried to make the replacement however, it returning form without performing replace.

Here's the code sample:

```
<?php
class test{
    function testing()
    {
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo 'TEST_TAG' ?>">
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', str_replace('TEST_TAG', wp_create_nonce('submit_of_form_lead'), (new test)->testing()));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning your form code with php but outputing it right away

The ?> is the php closing tag where you effectively say everything i write after this is not php anymore. Also the php echo outputs right away and does not return the string "TEST_TAG". What you can do to solve it is:

```
<?php
class test{
    function testing()
    {
        return '<input type="hidden" value="TEST_TAG">';
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', str_replace('TEST_TAG', wp_create_nonce('submit_of_form_lead'), (new test)->testing()));
?>
```

However this honestly would be a strange way to handle that what would be better is add a parameter to the function call and give this to where you call the form.

```
<?php
class test{
    function testing($value)
    {
        return "<input type='hidden' value='$value'>";
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', (new test)->testing(wp_create_nonce('submit_of_form_lead')));
?>
```

This should give the same result without having to replace the placeholder.